# Make block element overlap absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how i can achieve the following:

I have two divs. One is positioned absolutely, while the other is a simple block element. I need the block element to actually overlap the absolutely positioned container.

Here's a picture of what i need to do:
The red box is positioned absolutely, the blue box is a normal block element (inside a flexbox, but i don't think that changes anything, correct me if im wrong)
[image: Overlapping Divs]

I've tried achieving this with z-index, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Edit: Here's a fiddle to show more or less my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/xzp284vn/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
  </div>
  <div class="absolute">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
     width: 40px;
  height: 300px;
}

.absolute {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
   width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: We need to see your code to help. But most likely your z-index didn't work because the blue element did not have a `position` property applied to it.

Comment: I have added a fiddle

Comment: add z-index to block and you are done

Answer (score 0):

```css
.red{
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.blue{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  right:30px;
  top:9px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="red">
  
  </div>
  <div class="blue">
    
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

This is what you are looking for..

Comment: The red block has to be absolutely positioned, and the blue block has to be normally/relative positioned